# Contracts: Will this be possible?

Tags: contracts

I would like to know if this will be possible with Bitcoin:

Create a key with the following features:

1. Only be able to spend btc if a % of pre-definied keys allow it
2. The own of the key need for example 80% acceptance from pre-definied keys to be able to spend btc (same process to each transaction)
3. If 80% is not reached, nothing happens
4. Specify a time to people (pre-definied keys) vote agree or deny

Comment: It's certainly possible. But currently, you'll have to do all the work yourself to sign/release the transaction if, and only if, your particular contract requirements are met. The Bitcoin client/network won't help you ... yet!

Answer (score 4):

The protocol already supports transactions where x out of y keys need to agree in order to spend the coins.

The protocol will never support transactions that change/expire automatically after some period of time, as this causes problems.

Comment: Problems? Got a reference for that?

Comment: It's not allowed for transactions to become invalid due to scripts/conditions. They can become valid, but never invalid. See https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1786.msg22119#msg22119